# Nested loops and cloning of lists

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, copy, cloning

I have a list of dicts

```
lst = [{"activity":"tx"},{"activity":"fl", "ids":['123','456','789','432']}, {"activity":"ia"}]
```

I would like to clone these lists and add them to a master list, where the number is based on the unique "ids" in the "fl" dict.

desired outcome:

```
master = [[{"activity":"tx"},{"activity":"fl", "ids":'123'}, {"activity":"ia"}], 
          [{"activity":"tx"},{"activity":"fl", "ids":'456'}, {"activity":"ia"}], 
          [{"activity":"tx"},{"activity":"fl", "ids":'789'}, {"activity":"ia"}], 
          [{"activity":"tx"},{"activity":"fl", "ids":'432'}, {"activity":"ia"}]]
```

Comment: Great; you’ve defined the problem. What have you tried so far, and what’s going wrong with it? Please show us your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple loop on `lst[1]['ids']`

```
ans = [[lst[0], {"activity":"fl", "ids": id}, lst[2]] for id in lst[1]['ids']]

print(ans)  
[[{'activity': 'tx'}, {'activity': 'fl', 'ids': '123'}, {'activity': 'ia'}],
 [{'activity': 'tx'}, {'activity': 'fl', 'ids': '456'}, {'activity': 'ia'}],
 [{'activity': 'tx'}, {'activity': 'fl', 'ids': '789'}, {'activity': 'ia'}],
 [{'activity': 'tx'}, {'activity': 'fl', 'ids': '432'}, {'activity': 'ia'}]]
```